# Avoid jpa fetch eager with join table

Tags: java, jpa

I have the next classes:

A class User:

```
@Entity
@JsonRootName(value = "user")
@Table(name = "web_users", schema = "t_dw_comercial")
public class User {


   @Id
   private int userId;

   private String fullName;

   private String ldapId;

   private String email;


   @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name= "u_type", nullable=false)
    private Role uType;

    private String deleteFlag;

    private String typeAccess;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="web_users_roles",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id")},
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id")}
    )
    private List<Role> roles;

}
```

A class Role:

```
@Entity
@JsonRootName(value = "roles")
@Table(name = "web_roles", schema = "t_dw_comercial")
public class Role {

   @Id
   private int roleId;

   private String roleName;

   @OneToMany 
   @JoinTable(name="web_users_roles",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="user_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="role_id")})
   private List<Section> sections = new ArrayList<Section>();


}
```

Service:

```
@Service
public class UserService implements IUserService{

    @Autowired
    UserRepository repository;

    public User findUserByLdapId(String loginName) {

        return repository.findUserByLdapId(loginName);
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long>{

    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u where u.ldapId= ?1")
public User findUserByLdapId(String loginName);


}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private IUserService userService;

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/dashboard", params = {"user"}, method = RequestMethod.GET,  produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<User>  getUser(@RequestParam(value = "user") String ldapId) {

        User user =  userService.findUserByLdapId(ldapId);

        if(user == null)
            return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);

        return new ResponseEntity<>(user, HttpStatus.OK);

    };
}
```

As you can see I have a role in a user and a list of roles. The one called uType would be something like a main role, and the list, secondary roles. I know that this role will appear twice but I don't care about it at all.

I would like to have the main role fetched eager and the list of roles fetched lazy, on demand, is it possible?

So a json would looks like:

```
{
    "user": {
        "userId": 1,
        "fullName": "Carolina Ponce",
        "ldapId": "f8cygqn",
        "email": "carolina@blabla.com",
        "uType": {
            "roleId": 1,
            "roleName": "Admin",
            "sections": [
                {
                    "sectionId": 2,
                    "sectionName": "Admin",
                    "components": []
                },
                {
                    "sectionId": 1,
                    "sectionName": "Dashboard",
                    "components": [
                        {
                            "componentId": 2,
                            "componentName": "Provincia",
                            "jsonArray": [
                                {
                                    "ID": "6",
                                    "NAME": "BUENOS AIRES"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "componentId": 1,
                            "componentName": "Rubros",
                            "jsonArray": [
                                {
                                    "ID": "1",
                                    "NAME": "Automotriz"
                                },
                                {
                                    "ID": "31",
                                    "NAME": "Universidades"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        "deleteFlag": "",
        "typeAccess": ""
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Entity graphs](https://thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-entity-graph-part-1-named-entity/) are intended for that. The last time I checked, it was in JPA but not available in Hibernate. It seems that it is now available in Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your questions correctly as Jpa/Hibernate does this by default. All *ToOne relationships are eager by default, while all *ToMany are lazy by default.

From the docs of `@OneToMany`.

```
public abstract FetchType fetch

    (Optional) Whether the association should be lazily loaded or must be eagerly
    fetched. The EAGER strategy is a requirement on the persistence provider runtime 
    that the associated entities must be eagerly fetched. The LAZY strategy is a 
    hint to the persistence provider runtime.

Default:
    javax.persistence.FetchType.LAZY
```

And from the docs of `@ManyToOne`

```
public abstract FetchType fetch

   (Optional) Whether the association should be lazily loaded or must be eagerly 
   fetched. The EAGER strategy is a requirement on the persistence provider runtime
   that the associated entity must be eagerly fetched. The LAZY strategy is a hint 
   to the persistence provider runtime.

Default:
   javax.persistence.FetchType.EAGER
```

Comment: I know but even with both annotations, for differents atributes of the same class I get al the data retrieved eagerly.

Comment: That is very, very strange. I wonder if something else in the code is forcing the collection to be eagerly loaded (e.g. something iterating the collection). Can you enable logging of SQL statements and debug the JPA call that loads a `User`? If there you cannot see the join with `role.user_id`, then you can be for sure that something else is forcing to load the collection.

Comment: Could be the @joinedTable? I can't find any other possibility.

Comment: I can't think of what else could be rather than a piece of code that is iterating through the collection, and as a consequence forcing it to load. I don't think `@joinedTable` would be the culprit as this annotation shouldn't affect the lazy/eager load (as far as I know).

Comment: I edited and added other classes, controller, service and repository, thats all I have.